# How to transfer pictures from hangouts onto my computer

Tags: storage, images, google-hangouts

How can I transfer the pictures that are on my android hangouts (sent and received messages), so that I can preserve them before I clear my android for space?

Answer (score 1):

I think those are saved at Google and synced across all your devices. Try and log in from a PC, go to gmail.com, then look your hangouts to the left. If you can see your pictures there, it's safe to wipe your phone. You can also save the pictures from there to your PC if you want - but they're safe where they are.